# Remove authors command execution discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

i want my bot to delete the authors message after the command is executed. I have tried all kinds of variations, but can not figure it out.
Here is the code:

```
   async def kronellermynt(ctx):
     kronellermyntlist = ["Kron", "Mynt"]
     responseone = random.choice(kronellermyntlist)
     await ctx.send(responseone)
     await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: What is `ctx`? The channel?

Comment: It stands for context, and is used when defining commands for discord bots.

Comment: Your code runs fine and deletes the message in the Async Branch. What happens when you run it. I get a `message delete` entry in the console, along with the response one message being sent and the original message being deleted?

Comment: Does the bot have permission to delete messages in that channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this could work:

```
import random

@bot.command()
async def kronellermynt(ctx):
     await ctx.message.delete()
     list = ["Kron", "Mynt"]
     await ctx.send(random.choice(list))
```

also check terminal for errors (if bot haven't got manage_messages permission)

Comment: also `@client.command()` (if you set `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=[prefix])`